How to show newly created image in wwwroot on MAUI desktop app?
I have a MAUI/Razor Project for desktop app. When I click the button "create Chart", an new bmp image is created in wwwroot/chart/. But it doesn't show up in the app. Only after I restart the app, it shows up.
How can I make such an image show up immediately after it is created? Maybe something like reload wwwroot?
Razor （ https://www.blazor.zone/image-viewer ）:
@page "/notfallberechnung"

<div class="row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">
            <button @onclick="CreateChartAsync">Create Chart</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">            
            <ImageViewer Url="@currentChartPath" FitMode="ObjectFitMode.Fill" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

cs:
using BootstrapBlazor.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Expo.Pages
{
    public partial class Notfallberechnung : ComponentBase
    {
        private string currentChartPath = "./chart/Mode-5000.bmp";
        public async void CreateChartAsync()
        {
            var n = new Bitmap(314, 314);
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(n))
            {                   
                g.DrawString("hallo test", new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red), 200, 200);
            }
            int length = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.LastIndexOf(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName) + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Length + 1;
            string sub = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Substring(0, length);
            var fileName = sub + "wwwroot\\chart\\Mode-5000.bmp";
            n.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);              
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}

source code: https://github.com/uliloewi/ForFix
no image. although it is created just now:




after restart:



Could you provide a Minimal, Reproducible sample? In addition, why the url that error shows is https://0.0.0.0/.......Kurzzeit-Summe-KKG1Mode-500.bmp, but the image is https://0.0.0.0/.......Kurzzeit-Summe-KKG1Mode-5000.bmp? 500 or 5000?

500 or 5000 doesnt matter. They are in wwwroot/chart. The codes are inserted in the modified issue.

Could you provide more code so that I can reproduce your question?

sure. All codes of the files are inserted in the modified issue.

...I still can not reproduce the question, see this.

source code is here
https://github.com/uliloewi/ForFix

Where is your wwwroot folder? And I tested the sample you provided, it shows this.

source is modified on github

You can use the following code:
namespace Expo.Pages
{
    public partial class Notfallberechnung : ComponentBase
    {
        private string currentChartPath;
        public async void CreateChartAsync()
        {
            var n = new Bitmap(314, 314);
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(n))
            {                   
                g.DrawString("————hallo test", new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red), 200, 200);
            }
            int length = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.LastIndexOf(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName) + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Length + 1;
            //string sub = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Substring(0, length);
            string sub = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "wwwroot", "chart");
            if (!Directory.Exists(sub)) 
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(sub);
            }
            //var fileName = sub + "wwwroot\\chart\\Mode-5000.bmp";
            var fileName = Path.Combine(sub, "Mode-5000.bmp");
            n.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            StateHasChanged();
            currentChartPath = "./chart/Mode-5000.bmp";
        }
    }
}

